# segue "show (e.g push) selected but show detail (e.g replace) on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I have added a segue to my storyboard and selected the show (e.g push) option. It works in the storyboard like you can see in the picture:

[image]

but when I try to simulate it on my iPhone it changes to this:

[image: ft]

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you executing the segue?

Comment: It was added via the storyboard -> button to viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the presentation style.[image: Presentation Style]

Comment: Tried that but nothing changed